# vb.net datatable to List(of T) 3.5

Tags: vb.net, list, datatable

I search a way to convert a dataTable to List(of T).

In Vb.net on .Net 3.5

If you know How To or maybe a link of somebody who did it.

tank you

---

I check this on c# (from another stack question)

```
public static IEnumerable<T> ToEnumerable<T>(DataTable dt, Func<DataRow, T> translator)
{
    foreach(DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    {
       yield return translator(dr);
    }
}
```

but I cant translate Func on .net 3.5 (I didnt found how to do it. or the good lib)

Comment: [`DataTableExtensions.AsEnumerable` Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatableextensions.asenumerable%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the reference to the following assembly:

C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.5\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll

otherwise you can´t call the AsEnumerable() method.

Tim Schmelter wrote an additional tip:

You need to add a reference to System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll. In VB.NET you don't need to call it explicitely(Dim rows = (From row in dt).ToList).

Berry

Comment: yeah, already see that, seems working. (or at least compile). but I was expecting the translation of the second code of this post : List<DataRow> drlist = dt.AsEnumerable().ToList(); // but I cant do .AsEnumerable, datatable doesnt have this property.

Comment: Oh i thought they have. http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.data.datatableextensions.asenumerable.aspx

Comment: Maybe you need that reference: http://mitzen.blogspot.de/2009/06/datatable-does-not-have-asenumerable.html

Comment: @forX: You need to add a reference to `System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll`. In VB.NET you don't need to call it explicitely:`(From row in dt).ToList` returns a `List(Of DataRow)`.

Comment: tank you. I will look at that.